# Can I apply functions to infinite matrices or linear operators in Mathematica?

Tags: matrix, operators

I do not know how can I apply functions to infinite matrices or linear operators.
For instance, having the derivative operator, what is its sine?

For instance, for finite derivative operator we have

$$\sin\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & -4 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & -10 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

But the derivative operator has infinite matrix. Is it possible to get results this way with expression for $(i,j)$-th element of the matrix? Or apply the resulting operator (defined as an expression on $D$, such as $\Delta=e^D-1$, $f(x+5)=e^{5D}$, $\int f(x)dx=1/D$) to an arbitrary function?

Comment: How would you even represent a linear operator? You could only at the least represent leading submatrices...

Comment: @J.M. well there could be a common expression for its components $a_{ij}$

Comment: @J.M. also, some operators can be represented as expressions of the derivative operator. For instance, $\Delta=e^D-1$, $f(x+5)=e^{5D}$, $\int f(x)dx=1/D$

Comment: I see; please edit your question to include those desired possible answers.

Comment: @J.M. I wondered, how can I apply, say, sine of derivative to an arbitrary function.

Comment: Do you want only the operator, or will you apply the operator later? `MatrixFunction` can be used on an operator with finite matrix.

Comment: @SneezeFor16Min I am asking for infinite case.

Comment: Infinite matrix products are matrices of infinite sums of products of elements. The only way this can make sense is if you have expressions for the elements. Then you may attempt to use `Sum` to find an expression for the product elements. Note that your element definitions must not be procedural: `Sum` cannot "reason" about the properties of programs.